# Error While trying to view PDF document in browser it just get downloaded [ASP.net Core 3.0]

Tags: asp.net-core, pdf-viewer

I have tried to view pdf documents in my ASP.net core application but when I clicked on Read button the pdf document just get downloaded 
Here is My Code
**In my Home Controller I have GetPdf Action**

```
  public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
        {
            string filePath = "~/file/" + fileName;
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
            return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
        }
```

and in the View part I have used

```
 <a href="/Home/GetPdf/php.pdf" class="btn btn-default">Read</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off any download manager software installed on your system. When you try to read the pdf the download manager will take it over to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ActionMethod to this -

```
  public ActionResult GetPdf(string fileName)
        {
            string filePath = "~/file/" + fileName;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
            return File(filePath, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Note the change of `Response.Headers.Add` to `Response.AddHeader`

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. and the other problem was I just need to turn off IDM otherwise it just gets downloaded